# Counting measure is the countable sum of the Dirac measures

Tags: measure-theory

$(\mathbb{N}, \mathcal{P}(\mathbb{N}), \mu)$. Let $\mu$  be the counting measure.
Let $\delta_j$ be the Dirac mass at the point $j\in\Bbb N$. Is it the case that $\mu=\sum_{j=1}^{\infty} \delta_{j}$ ?

Comment: Yes it is. Just evaluate the sum of the dirac measures on a set, and see what you get.

Comment: Too see I matches, right? @Milten

Comment: Yes, that's right